# IDA Pro/IDAPython automation through IDAPython

Tags: ida, idapython, ida-plugin, bin-diffing, tool-bindiff

I have been trying to use IDA Pro (with bindiff) via IDAPython to automate the analysis process of a bios.dump file while outputting the results to a .txt / .asm file. From here I want to use the bindiff functions to compare this database with another database and output any differences to a file.  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the now free [BinDiff 4.2](https://www.zynamics.com/software.html) you can do batch analysis with a bit of work.

In the BinDiff installation directory (`zynamics/BinDiff 4.2`), you will find `bin/differ.exe` and `bin/differ64.exe`. Those are binaries for batch diffing of IDBs and `.BinExport` files.

The basic usage would be:

```
differ --primary=<directory-with-IDBs> --output-dir=<output-directory>
```

Sadly, this does not work (at least on my machine) as `differ.exe` fails to find IDA's executable and tries to execute the directory instead.

To solve this, we will export IDBs using the following command:

```
"<path-to-idaq.exe>" -A -OExporterModule:<result-directory> -S"<path-to-export-script>" "<path-to-idb>"
```

The `export-script` is an `.idc` with the following code:

```
#include <idc.idc>

static main()
{
    Batch(0);
    Wait();
    Exit(1 - RunPlugin("zynamics_binexport_8", 2));
}
```

Once you have all your `.BinExport` files in one directory, run the original `differ.exe` command on that directory (give it the directory with the `.BinExport` files instead of the `.idb` files), and you'll get `.BinDiff` files for all possible diffs. Those can either be opened up in IDA, or manually parsed (they are SQLite databases).

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking about using BinDiff in batch mode: sorry, you can't. It's intentionally restricted.

Comment: For what reason is it restricted?

Comment: VxClass, I guess. But I don't know the reason, sorry.

Comment: Do you know any other software I might investigate that could be called remotely to compare two binary/BIOS files?

Comment: There are a lot of diffing tools (kdiff, etc...), but those are not like BinDiff.

Comment: Is there anyway that I can export the bindiff results into a readable text (.txt) file? I can only seem to view the results through IDA GUI and .BinExports are not what I am looking for when sending reports.